# boost directory_iterator receiving SIGABRT

Tags: boost, sigabrt, boost-iterators

I'm using boost/filesystem for iterating directory and add them to Zip file on MacOSX + XCode3.

My original logic looks like this

```
path targetDir( "Volumes/data/some_directory" );
directory_iterator it( targetDir ), eod;

std::string filename;
std::string strPath;

// I tried both of two types of making loop
for( ; it != eod ; ++it )
{
    path const& p = *it;
    filename = p.filename();
    if( is_directory(p) )
    {
        strPath = strDirectory + filename + string("/");

        // Initially I wanted this logic to be recursive(these code block is a part of PackDirectory)
        PackDirectory( archive, strPath, lpszPackFile );
    }
    else if( is_regular_file(p) )
    {
        strPath = strDirectory + filename;
        // add this file to specified Zip file here
    }

}

then function returns here.
```

The problem arises after returning this function, specifically when destructor of directory_iterator is called, I guess. It seems it deletes invalid pointer, and receiving SIGABRT.
Program sometimes crashes like below, and sometimes it freezes when I hit step over, XCode says "stepping over" but nothing proceeds with call stack disappearing.
AND the point is, problem remains even if I don't do anything inside the loop, which means when variables are simply created and function returned.

for more information, call stack looks like this when program crashes.

```
#0  0x93f86c5a in __kill
#1  0x93f86c4c in kill$UNIX2003
#2  0x940195a5 in raise
#3  0x9402f6e4 in abort
#4  0x93f2c575 in free
#5  0x00134aea in dir_itr_close [inlined] at v2_operations.cpp:1300
#6  0x00134aea in ~dir_itr_imp [inlined] at operations.hpp:877
#7  0x00134aea in     checked_delete<boost::filesystem2::detail::dir_itr_imp<boost::filesystem2::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem2::path_traits> > > [inlined] at checked_delete.hpp:34
#8  0x00134aea in boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::filesystem2::detail::dir_itr_imp<boost::filesystem2::basic_path<std::string, boost::filesystem2::path_traits> > >::dispose at v2_operations.cpp:78
#9  0x00136583 in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::weak_release at sp_counted_base_pt.hpp:97
```

It goes into ~dir_itr_imp, so it seems it reaches correct destructor after passing type checking.

Did I do something wrong with directory_iterator?
If someone went through this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signal that is raised in `free` does not necessarily point to a defect in the calling functions. An earlier and broken call to `free` could have corrupted `malloc`'s free memory list, and thereby caused the error.

Try running your program in `valgrind`, which is more robust and will die immediately when corrupt memory allocation/deallocation is used. If `valgrind` is not an option, you can also try to test your code in a unit test independently of the rest of the program.

Comment: It was XCode bug. Some breakpoints are different from actual debugging line, so it deletes directory_iterator twice somehow. I'm updating my XCode to 4.2 now. Thank you for the help, btw :)